# Select2 in angular js

Tags: angularjs

The select2 box is not working when route change.I need to trigger the select2 box when route change. But below code is not working for me. Is there any option to trigger the select2 box

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        $( "select" ).select2({
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
            theme: "bootstrap4"
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `'$routeChangeStart'` instead of `'$routeChangeSuccess'`.

Comment: I used nothing reflected.